# Reprinting line after receiving input

Tags: java, input, printing, terminal

How would you reprint a line after taking an input from the user (from terminal)?

I realise that you could reprint a line using:

```
 System.out.print("\r foo");
 System.out.print("\r bar");
```

Which will produce the output:

```
 bar
```

but once you take an input from the user, this doesn't seem to work. For instance:

```
System.out.print("\r foo");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("\r bar");
```

If you type in 1 as the input, you get:

```
 foo1
 bar
```

Can you reprint on the same line as foo (or more specifically, foo1) once the user has provided an input?

Comment: Well, you're not on that line anymore, so `\r` won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is likely to be "raw" vs "cooked" mode of input.  To do what you want, you will need to use "raw" mode where you collect each character as it is typed, and decide what to do with it, including whether you echo it to the console or not.

Cooked mode is more common for simple command line program input, and basically means "Give me the user's input, one line at a time".  And "one line at a time" generally translates to "when the user presses enter."  Most "cooked" implementations echo the keyboard input to the console.

For a host of reasons, doing "raw" mode in CLI programs is difficult -- not impossible, but difficult.  I will spare the details in this venue (which are numerous and do not lend themselves to easy copy and paste here), and instead point you to the resource I used when attempting the same a few years ago:

[Non blocking console input in Python and Java](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/)

A quick *hunteke* summary: the terminal/console needs to change state, not just your program, and there is no portable method for doing so.  You'll be outsourcing to other libraries or programs to do what you want -- just don't forget to undo it when your program quits, or your users won't be happy!